# Emulation of 8088 CPU with Video System

Tags: emulation

I thinking about writing simple 8088 emulator. But I can't understand how to connect 8088 core with video subsystem.

I thinking about main loop:

```
while (TRUE)
{
   execute_cpu_cycles_per_scanline() ; 
   paint_scanline() ; 
}
```

Does this method is suitable for CPU and graphics emulation? Any other methods ? Any good explanation why I can't use different threads for CPU and Video. How dealing with this problem emulators like QEMU or others (x86).

Thanks.

Comment: You might have to have a copy of the BIOS that interracts with the video subsystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well there are so many x86 processors and as they have evolved over time the instructions to clock periods have become somewhat non-deterministic.  For older cpus like the 8088 and 6502, etc, if documented and accurate you could simply count the clock cycles for each instruction, and when the number of simulated clock cycles is equal to or greater than the scanline draw time or some interrupt interval or whatever then you could do what you are suggesting.  and if you look at mame for example or other emulators that is basically how they do it, use the instructions clock cycles to determine time elapsed and from that manage emulated time in the peripherals.

lets say you want to run linux on qemu, you wouldnt want the emulated clock that tells time to be determined by the execution of instructions, you would want to sync that clock with the hardware system clock.  Likewise you might want to sync the refresh rates based on the real hardware refresh rates rather than simulated ones.

so those are the two extremes.  you will need to do one or the other or something in between.

Comment: Hello dwelch. Nice to hear you. Actually I'm counting CPU cycles. So it's not problem for me. I just want to know good way how to integrate CPU and Video in one loop. So in my example I'm executing CPU cycles per one scanline. Does it's proper way ? Maybe I need to execute cycles for one frame and then update whole screen or something else ?

Comment: eventually is that video going somewhere?  is there some real hardware tied to that video?  if you fake the scanlines then later have to sync your fake video to real video that adds to the problem.  If the exercise here is to have code that feels like the old days then try to get the scanline time right, if there is another goal like emulating a game good enough.  Then perhaps just use the real hardware

Comment: there is no proper way it depends on what you are trying to do, how pure you want the emulation to be compared to the hardware you are emulating.  On the other hand maybe you just want to have the software run and not care about hardware accuracy but the user experience of running the software, why arbitrarily make it slower if the goal is to use the software for example?